# Indepent variables and these functions

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics, independence

Random variables $x_1, x_2,...,x_n$ are independent. Then I want to show whether these functions $$y_1=f_1(x) \\  y_2=f_2(x) \\ ... \\ y_n=f_n(x)$$ are independent or not .

How to prove this?

Comment: This question makes no sense: after introducing $n$ *variables*, you then ask about $n$ otherwise undefined *functions.*  So that others are not lured into answering a question you did not mean to ask, I will close this until you have edited the question to your satisfaction, it is unlikely to change further, and then the community--if it agrees the question can be answered--votes to reopen it.

Answer (score 3):

Write down the joint distribution of all variables, marginalize out the $x$'s, and show that the result factorizes over the $y$'s.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake while writing functions. These should be eqaul to $f(x)$. Please explain the proof more explicitly for this changed functions.

Comment: The modified question does not make sense.  I think the original question was the right one.

Comment: My instructor said that for example $y_1= x_1+x_3+x_5$ other $y_2, y_3,...$ are different combinations of $x_i$ thus, $y_i$ is equl to $f(x)$. @TomMinka

Comment: Sorry , then I Will write $y_i$'s as $f_i(x)$. Now, everything is correct. Please show your answer more detail :)

Comment: You cannot prove independence for this modified question since the $y$'s are not going to be independent in general.

Comment: Well, how to show not to be independent?

Comment: Because if $f_1 = f_2$ then obviously $y_1$ and $y_2$ are dependent.  This modified question really doesn't make sense at all.